# Should I add code to my answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, specific-answer, quality-improvement

I just answered a question and I keep on asking myself should I have added example code.
The user asked why his code was not doing what he expected.

I added an answer explaining why his concept was not working. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73321590/21111370)

I could correct the code to give a working example. I did not because in my opinion this is a better way of learning.
Would it improve my answer if I added code?

Comment: If you feel that not sharing code is better for learning how about sharing pseudo code instead? I feel that sharing pseudo code that points out the problem / mistake OP makes in a concise manner would surely improve the answer.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a school. It is about getting answers to practical problems, hopefully efficiently so (ideally using a search engine, not asking a question). Learning is only incidental.

Comment: *"I did not because in my opinion this is a better way of learning."* - but that is not what Stack Overflow is for, Stack Overflow is not a schooling environment. Don't use Stack Overflow as you please, use it as intended. So write factually correct and complete answers. Whether someone learns something or not is entirely the responsibility of the reader, not yours.

Comment: Too many of the comments here imply that you are misusing Stack Overflow and/or that there is something wrong with your answer. I disagree with that. Your answer is fine, answers do not need to contain copy-pasta-ready snippets, and it's a perfectly valid position and/or use of Stack Overflow to assume that askers/researchers want to learn and understand *why*. Now, that doesn't mean that also including code snippets along with an explanation is bad. Whether you do that is up to you, and should really be decided on a case-by-case basis.

Answer (score 9):

Answer the question however you like, but be sure to keep in mind that it's not *just* the OP that you'll be helping with such an answer.

If you think that not adding code is sufficient enough, don't add any code.  If you want to add code to fill in missing details to make a concept clearer, go for it.

Comment: As an aside, I'm really not a fan of "they won't learn if they just get shown code"-style approaches.  Everyone is going to be looking up code and copying examples from *somewhere*, and if someone decides that your wall of text is tl;dr then they'll move to another place where they can copy an example from and learn that way.  It's not that I disagree with the approach, I'm just not a fan since it doesn't accomplish what you're going for, ultimately.

Comment: It was clever of you to put that aside in a comment, because that nullifies my ability to downvote it. "Everyone" isn't going to be copying examples from somewhere, unless I was recently demoted to "not a person" status. And even if you dislike the paternalism, it remains valid to hold the position that they're not going to fail to learn because of *me*. That may well be all that an author is going for. Equally, if someone decides that all these "snippet"-style answers are useless, then they'll move to another place where they can read and understand. I hope that place is here.

Comment: @CodyGray:  The reason it's an aside is that it's not an answer to the question, it's just my opinion on the matter.  There's always subjectivity to the matter on this, in that - to be blunt - there are more places to get answers that can be more copy-paste-learn-friendly to a user.  Someone who thinks that they are actively helping someone learn a concept by withholding their ability to take the code and play with it directly is...I dunno, at *best* misinformed?

Comment: @CodyGray:  There's other sentiments of giving someone like a student Just Enough™ to work with but not enough to wholesale cheat on their homework, and there's also a desire to not let some worker try to outsource their work on us, which I get and agree with, but I have to stress that in my personal opinion, we're not going to be all things to all people, and the kind of "help" we provide and the value it provides is not something that we individually can quantify.  If someone wants more meat, sure I would hope they get it from here.  What are the answers giving now?  Mostly copy and paste.